# How to execute arbitrary parameterized SQL in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-injection

For performance reasons, I need to write a new method in my Rails model that executes some arbitrary SQL:

```
UPDATE table
   SET col1 = ? AND col2 = ?
   WHERE id = ?
```

I understand I can use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` or `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.update` with a string of SQL to get the results I need, but what is the proper procedure for substituting the parameter placeholders (`?`) with the actual parameter values? Is there a Rails method for interpolating parameters into a SQL statement, or should it just be done by manual interpolation? The latter seems unsafe...

Comment: Check out this question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483049/how-to-execute-a-raw-update-sql-with-dynamic-binding-in-rails/4484549#4484549.

Comment: I second Brian's comment - the above link seems to be the same basic question.

Answer (score 5):

You could also do this:

```
updates = ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, ["name = ? and category = ?", name, category])
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("update table set #{updates} where id = #{id.to_s.to_i}")
```

`to_s` is being called on `id` before `to_i` in case it's nil.

Comment: This isnt answering the question, as it uses string interpolation and is thus vunerable to SQL injections. Yes I am aware its using "sanitized" sql array, but theres a long history of these things being a poor substitute for actual security. What is being asked for is access to parameterized queries like all sane dbms systems have had since the 1980s.