# Rails 3 connection.execute IN statement parameters array syntax

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, prepared-statement

I have a syntax question regarding the Rails 3 ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute method and parameter that i want to use with it. I have been fighting with this for some hours now and just do not seem to find any answers to this specific question on the internet.

The database is MySQL.

I need to create a temporary table through SELECT with IN condition statement, where the list of values against which IN should check, is a parameter - rails Array. The code looks like so:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE things SELECT * FROM objects WHERE objects.id IN #{arr}")
```

I get a MySQL syntax error!

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE things SELECT * FROM objects WHERE objects.id IN #{(arr)}")
```

Again MySQL syntax error!

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE things SELECT * FROM objects WHERE objects.id IN (#{arr})")
```

MySQL syntax error

The above attempts correspond to this question-answer:
[How to execute arbitrary parameterized SQL in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556672/how-to-execute-arbitrary-parameterized-sql-in-rails)

I even tried to use in the manner like with find_by_sql, but still get an error:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(["CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE things SELECT * FROM objects WHERE objects.id IN (:ids)",{:ids => arr }]) - obviously, I get an MySQL error.
```

Am I missing something obvious? Please help! I need this exactly in this way (e.g. create temporary table with exactly such conditions), otherwise a more complicated query based on this one will not work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert `arr.to_s` you get `"[1, 2, 3]"`.

I think `arr.join(', ')` should work.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE things SELECT * FROM objects WHERE objects.id IN (#{arr.join(', ')})")
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's another option that uses Rails' query sanitization

```
arr = [1,2,3]
query = "SELECT * FROM objects where id IN (?)"
query = ActiveRecord::Base.send :sanitize_sql_array, [query, arr]
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```