# Escaping a single quotation within SQL query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, escaping

I have a table `companies`, which has two columns named `name` and `address`. By running the following code, new data are inserted into the table:

```
my_name = "my company name"
my_address = "ABC"

query = "INSERT INTO companies (name,address) VALUES ('#{my_name}','#{my_address}');"

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query);
```

If I change `my_name` value from `"my company name"` to `"John's company"`, I will get a syntax error. This is because the query becomes:

```
"INSERT INTO companies (name,address) VALUES ('John's company','ABC');"
```

and `'John's company'` has a single quotation mark within it.

Given that I have already used double quotation mark for the query string definition, how can I get rid of this error regarding the single quotation mark in my value?

Comment: if my_name.include?('\'') my_name.sub(/'/,'\'')  ?

Comment: This is a really bad idea... you risk SQL injection attacks even if you escape single quotes with backslashes.  You need to understand character encodings, but there is a serious (known) exploit to this naive approach.  Use bind parameters in your query and allow the DBMS to transport the values safely.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If you must do it this way then use the [`quote` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting.html#method-i-quote) on the connection object:

> **quote**(value, column = nil)
>   Quotes the column value to help prevent SQL injection attacks.

So something like this:

```
my_name    = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote("John O'Neil")
my_address = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote("R'lyeh")

query = "INSERT INTO companies (name,address) VALUES (#{my_name}, #{my_address})"

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query);
```

Never ever try to handle your own quoting. And don't try to use double quotes for quoting an SQL string literal, that's what single quotes are for; double quotes are for quoting identifiers (such as table and column names) in most databases but MySQL uses backticks for that.

Comment: Since I am using variable for my_name, I guess I can use my_name = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(NAME_VARIABLE)

Comment: @Leem.fin: Right. Or you could put it right inside the string interpolation but that would make your code harder to read.

Comment: I think there is an error in your code, you should remove the single quotation mark in the query VALUES part, since the quote() method has already added quotation mark for the string. Now if I run the code like you said, I got SQL syntax error since I have ' 'John's company' ' as the value

Comment: Doesn't active record support bind values? This sort of string escaping feels like more effort than it needs to be (and potentially riskier, if the escaping algorithm isn't too smart).  PHP granted, but there's an old discuss on the risks of simple backslash escaping here, including a demonstration http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string (it relates to character encoding hacks).  Usually when you use bind parameters, the DBMS transports the values for you, without interpolating them into the string.

Comment: Looking at the source of `#quote_string`, it looks vulnerable to this attack too.  Depends on the character set you're using.

Comment: Checkout this post as well for alternatives to what you want to do + how to sanitize your params http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483049/how-to-execute-a-raw-update-sql-with-dynamic-binding-in-rails

Comment: @d11wtq: I couldn't find any prepared statement support last time I looked but the AR documentation is, um, a little thin to be charitable. Rails often has more attitude than good sense, their way or the highway and all that adolescent trash. If the `quote` implementation is vulnerable then AR itself is vulnerable, AFAIK Rails doesn't use prepared statements and bound parameters internally (but perhaps they have fixed this since I last looked).

Comment: @user420504: That's definitely worth mentioning. I'm not sure how standardized the raw interfaces are but that might not matter.

Comment: @lynks: Lovecraft always seems appropriate when talking about such things, never call up what you can't put down and all that.

Comment: Is it possible to use this methodology when querying objects other than strings? I want to submit an SQL query containing an integer and two datetime objects.

Comment: @Argus9: Have you tried seeing what `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote` does with `Fixnum` and `Time` objects in the console? It should do The Right Thing.

Comment: Yeah, I took a look in my debugger console and see that it is, in fact, returning the proper variables. Thanks!