# Error inserting data into varchar that contains apostrophe?

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems

I have ruby script that includes a mysql insert that is working fine until it gets to a row that contains data containing an apostrophe. This row is also being populated using a variable and Im unsure how to escape the character so the insert will work successfully.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the quote method on the connection object:

```
quote(value, column = nil)
```

[API Documentation Link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting.html)

Quotes the column value to help prevent SQL injection attacks.
Example:

```
my_name    = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote("John O'Neil")
my_address = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote("R'lyeh")

query = "INSERT INTO companies (name,address) VALUES (#{my_name}, #{my_address})"

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query);
```

Original Post:

See this post: [Escaping a single quotation within SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179760/sql-query-execution-with-single-quotation-mark-value/8179894#8179894)

Comment: You might want to at least give someone credit when copying [their answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8179894/479863).

Comment: sorry @muistooshort, already updated my answer with original link.