# Rails: Saving string in database with single/double qoute without backslash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to save a record with the field record.name = `"blah'"`. It's been saving as `"blah\'"` and that gives me an error. I tryied to replace `"'"` with `"\'"` with `.gsub(" ' ","\\\\'")`, but that saves the string as `"test1\\\'"`. How could I save a name with qoutes without getting an error ?

Before saving or updating I output the string and it is shown this way: `"blah'"
In the controller it is being saved this way:`
@bewirtung.save!`

and when I get the query of saving in the server log, I see this string as : `"blah'\"'.

The error is this:

```
'Remote SQLExecDirect: [Pervasive][ODBC Client Interface][LNA][Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface]Syntax Error: UPDATE "Object": UPDATE "Object" SET "name" = 'blah\'', "LastChange" = '2018<< ??? >>-04-06 17:28:' from CONNECT:
  mysql2-0.3.21-x86 (mingw32) lib/mysql2/client.rb:80:in `block in query'
  mysql2-0.3.21-x86 (mingw32) lib/mysql2/client.rb:79:in `query'
  activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:309:in `block in execute'
  activerecord (4.2.7.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:484
```

Comment: Show how you save it. And how do you observe that it's been saved "incorrectly". Also, what's the error, exactly?

Comment: May be this link will help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179760/escaping-a-single-quotation-within-sql-query

Comment: Make sure your db must configure with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Add    encoding: utf8 in the database.yml

Comment: @VivekSingh these tables are in utf8 encoding