# Rails ActiveRecord mysql2 adapter, use PreparedStatement by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sequel, mysql2

PreparedStatement support for mysql2 has been already added in version 0.4.0, as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906437/how-do-you-create-prepared-statements-with-the-mysql2-gem/33403181)
As per following details in version 0.5.2 it still not uses prepared statement in all ORM queries internally:

```
Shipment.where(order_id: 78987898789)<br>
Shipment.where('order_id = ?', 56789876)
```

Mysql Log:

```
2019-03-10T13:20:01.722848Z  1072 Query SELECT `shipments`.* FROM `shipments` WHERE `shipments`.`order_id` = 78987898789<br>
2019-03-10T13:22:27.748687Z  1072 Query SELECT `shipments`.* FROM `shipments` WHERE (order_id = 56789876)
```

Is there a way to enable/disable it for all ORM queries? (Just like the PostgreSQL adapter [ref](https://medium.com/@devinburnette/be-prepared-7768d1a111e1)). Does enabling it impact adversely on overall application performance?

If not, I haven't given a try yet but is it possible to achieve this using [Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel), and how complex is migrating an existing application from MySQL2 to Sequel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveRecord with Mysql2 < 5, doesn't support configurable parameter to enable prepared_statement 
Code snippet from ActiveRecord 4.2.6

> connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb

```
module ConnectionAdapters
class Mysql2Adapter < AbstractMysqlAdapter
  ADAPTER_NAME = 'Mysql2'.freeze

  def initialize(connection, logger, connection_options, config)
    super
    @prepared_statements = false # No configurable param, default set to false
    configure_connection
  end
  ...
end
```

ActiveRecord with Mysql2 = 5.2.1 adapter support configurable parameter to enable prepared_statement
Code snippet from ActiveRecord 5.2.1

> connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb

```
module ConnectionAdapters
class Mysql2Adapter < AbstractMysqlAdapter
  ADAPTER_NAME = "Mysql2".freeze

  include MySQL::DatabaseStatements

  def initialize(connection, logger, connection_options, config)
    super
    @prepared_statements = false unless config.key?(:prepared_statements)
    configure_connection
  end
  ...
end
```

So, in ActiveRecord 5.2.1, one can just add following line in database.yml to enable prepared_statements

> prepared_statements: true