# rails activerecord insert with binds

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, insert, mysql2, bind-variables

I am using mysql2 adaptor with activerecords in rails 3.2.6

I would like to use bind variables while doing a raw insert. I can not use a regular model since I am doing an insert into select.

Something like:

```
insert into t(col1, col2)
select ?, c
from t1
where t1.x = ?
```

I am new to Rails and was surprised how hard it is to do this. I understand this is not a regular rails convention of using Model classes etc. I would like to use bind variables for performance as well as security reasons. Ideally I do not want to use raw_connection as specified at [How to execute a raw update sql with dynamic binding in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483049/how-to-execute-a-raw-update-sql-with-dynamic-binding-in-rails)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
query = <<-SQL
insert into t(col1, col2)
select ?, c
from t1
where t1.x = ?
SQL

col1 = Model.columns.find{|x| x.name == 'col1'}
col2 = Model.columns.find{|x| x.name == 'col2'}

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.insert(query, nil, nil, nil, nil, [[col1, col1_value], [col2, col2_value]])
```

My source for how to make binds:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/test/cases/bind_parameter_test.rb

My source for how to do an insert:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-insert