# Rails has_many complicated query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm not quite sure how to word this but I'll give it a shot.

Basically I have two models: Message and Event.

Message belongs_to event and event has_many messages.

When I call something like:

```
Event.first.messages
```

It produces this output:

```
SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."event_id" = 1
```

What I would like to be able to do is keep the association between the two, but add another column into the has_many equation so the SQL produced is something like:

```
SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."event_id" = 1 OR "messages"."type_id" = 4
```

Where both the Message and Event tables contain a type_id column.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make pure ActiveRecord OR queries

Other ways to solve this

**Use SQL string as where argument:**

```
Message.where("event_id = ? or type_id = ?", Event.first.id, 4)
```

**Make 2 queries and then you add them:**

```
event_messages = Event.first.messages
type_messages = Message.where(:type_id => 4)
all_messages = event_messages + type_messages
```

**Raw SQL:**

[How to execute a raw update sql with dynamic binding in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483049/how-to-execute-a-raw-update-sql-with-dynamic-binding-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible By Using

```
Event.first.messages.where(:type_id => 4)
```

Try it

Comment: This would create an AND clause, whereby the question is about an OR. As far as I understand, OP wants to see all messages that are either directly associated by ID or have type_id = 4 (and ignore event_id in this case)

Comment: Correct, ignore the event_id if there is a matching type_id.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Event.first.find(:all, :conditions => ["where type_id = ? or event_id = ?", 4, 1])
```