# How to delete record from only associated table with has_and_belongs_to_many relation ship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two model `hotel` and `theme` and both has `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship

and third table name is `hotels_themes`, So I want to delete record only from third tables `hotels_themes`.

```
hotels_themes;
+----------+----------+
| hotel_id | theme_id |
+----------+----------+
|        8 |        4 |
|        9 |        5 |
|       11 |        2 |
|       11 |        4 |
|       11 |        6 |
|       12 |        2 |
|       12 |        5 |
+----------+----------+
```

I want to delete record which match hotel_id and theme_id.
Like sql query `delete from hotels_themes where hotel_id=9 and theme_id=5`

Answer (score 1):

Use the method [delete](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) added to HABTM collections:

```
hotel = Hotel.find(hotel_id)
theme = Theme.find(theme_id)
hotel.themes.delete(theme)
```

Comment: But this is not optimized way to do it. I want to write sql like "delete form hotels_themes where hotel_id=11 and theme_id=6"

Comment: @VijayChouhan I suppose you should use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483049/how-to-execute-a-raw-update-sql-with-dynamic-binding-in-rails) approach then.

Comment: @VijayChouhan I edited my answer with the Rails way of doing this. It has a minor drawback which is that `delete` takes an object as argument and not an id, so you need to fetch the `theme` first.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to empty out the association on either model instance depending on what you are trying to remove.  For example:

```
hotel.themes = []
# or
theme.hotels = []
```

Comment: If I want to delete hotel_id 11 and theme_id=6 then how to do it?