# Updating a record in SQLite?

Tags: ruby, sqlite

This code does NOT change the data in the column `fullname` in the `person` table, and it produces no error either.
I used the variable `$editKey` to fetch the record to edit, so it functions as planned:

```
def upDateRecord
  getInputs
  puts $editKey
  puts $fullname

  db = SQLite3::Database.open "ruby-test-02.db"
  db.execute "UPDATE person SET fullname = $fullname WHERE ID = $editKey"
rescue SQLite3::Exception => e 
  puts "Exception occured"
  puts e
ensure
  db.close

  puts $editKey
  puts $fullname      
end
```

Comment: `db.execute "UPDATE person SET fullname = #{$fullname} WHERE ID = #{$editKey}"` should work

Comment: Ruby is not PHP. You might want to read an introductional book about ruby (and its handling of variables in general and in regards to string interpolation). Also, in ruby `$foo` is a global variable (something which you shouldn't ever have to use except in very specific situations).

Comment: Also, in Ruby, variables and methods are written using snake_case, and classes are CamelCase. Also, look into using an ORM like [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net). It makes life SO much easier.

Comment: Yevgeniy: the solution you offered did not do the job; but thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute a raw update sql with dynamic binding in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483049/how-to-execute-a-raw-update-sql-with-dynamic-binding-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Sloved..

def upDateRecord
      puts "at upDateRecord"
      getInputs

```
  db = SQLite3::Database.new "ruby-test-02.db"
  stm = db.prepare "UPDATE person Set fullname=? WHERE ID=?"; stm.bind_param 1, $fullname; stm.bind_param 2, $editKey;stm.execute;stm.close
  stm = db.prepare "UPDATE person Set sex=? WHERE ID=?"; stm.bind_param 1, $sex; stm.bind_param 2, $editKey;stm.execute;stm.close
  stm = db.prepare "UPDATE person Set birth=? WHERE ID=?"; stm.bind_param 1, $birth; stm.bind_param 2, $editKey;stm.execute;stm.close
  stm = db.prepare "UPDATE person Set death=? WHERE ID=?"; stm.bind_param 1, $death; stm.bind_param 2, $editKey;stm.execute;stm.close
```

rescue SQLite3::Exception => e 
      puts "Exception occured"
      puts e
ensure
      db.close
    end