# Calculating difference between created_at and now() in rails update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have a column that should contains the difference between created_at and updated_at in minutes, so I tried to do the following but it usually saves the time_diff with zero. So, how can I fix that?

```
Product.update(
    id,
    time_diff: "((EXTRACT (DAY FROM (now()-created_at))*24*60*60+
                    EXTRACT (HOUR FROM (now()-created_at))*60*60+
                    EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM (now()-created_at))*60+
                    EXTRACT (SECOND FROM (now()-created_at)))/60)::int"
  )
```

The Extract query works fine in SQL but it doesn't work inside activerecord's update.

Answer (score 3):

Lot of ways for time difference. You can make custom method of time difference like:

```
def time_diff(start_time, end_time)
  seconds_diff = (start_time - end_time).to_i.abs

  hours = seconds_diff / 3600
  seconds_diff -= hours * 3600

  minutes = seconds_diff / 60
  seconds_diff -= minutes * 60

  seconds = seconds_diff

  "#{hours.to_s.rjust(2, '0')}:#{minutes.to_s.rjust(2, '0')}:#{seconds.to_s.rjust(2, '0')}"
end
```

And Use it

```
time_diff(updated_at, created_at) #just example
```

Or you can use ruby gem [time_difference](https://github.com/tmlee/time_difference)

Comment: I want to make it in one step when using activerecord .update... don't want to get the data and calculate the difference then save the date

Comment: @MahmoudM.Abdel-Fattah write a callback 

    after_save :update_time_diff  # product.rb 
    def update_time_diff
          update_attributes(time_diff:  (update_at - created_at)/60 )
    end
  
  hopefully it will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

`extract (epoch ...)` gives an interval in seconds, so use:

```
select extract (
    epoch from now() - '2015-09-14 03:06:02.848+02'::timestamp)::int/60 
    as minutes;

 minutes
---------
       7
(1 row)
```

Comment: Actually, the extract works fine SQL-Side but the problem is with Rails activerecord's update

Comment: Maybe this post could help: [How to execute a raw update sql with dynamic binding in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483049/how-to-execute-a-raw-update-sql-with-dynamic-binding-in-rails)