# Is it possible to put variables into my query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, activerecord

I've got a postgresql query using some ActiveRecord from Ruby On Rails

```
my_table.location = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE my_table SET location = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(my_table.longitude, my_table.latitude), 4326)::geography")
```

I want to put variables into my query like that because I don't want to use the column longitude and latitude from the database but rather some variables containing longitude and latitude values.

```
my_table.location = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE my_table SET location = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint((?), (?), 4326)::geography"), longitude, latitude)
```

I can't find a way to make it work but you should understand the idea behind. Does it exist some method to use variables in my query ?

Comment: tell me did it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a raw update sql with dynamic binding in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483049/how-to-execute-a-raw-update-sql-with-dynamic-binding-in-rails)

Comment: Well it worked partially, when my longitude and latitude values are nil it displays this error : `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "" (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can easily do it. Make sure to sanitize the query before passing it to the database. I have here used the method [quote](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting.html#method-i-quote). Also, read the comment by KNejad for more detail

```
 conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
 @from = conn.quote(params["from"))
 @to = conn.quote(params["to"))

 
 @from_date = Time.parse(@from).to_date.beginning_of_day
 @till_date = Time.parse(@to).to_date.end_of_day
          
 sql = "select abc.sss,im.lat,
 im.long from  users as rq JOIN  images as 
 im ON rq.id= im.imageable_id where  rq.created_at  
 BETWEEN '#{@from_date}' AND '#{@till_date}' ;" 
  
 response = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Are you using the same thing as suggested below ?

Comment: did you understand how to use variable in your sql query i have shown you one of my example

Comment: '#{longitude}' you can use this if it doesn't work then use #{longitude}

Comment: Yeah thanks, i think i understood well, trying to adjust to my case, will mark as answered right after.

Comment: This works fine in this case, but you should note that if the @from_date is coming directly from the user, this is susceptible to an SQL Injection attack. So you should always make sure to sanitise the data before passing it to the database (e.g. by parsing it into a date object, like this answer is doing)

Comment: @KNejad  I have updated my answer as per your suggestion

Comment: @AniketTiwari your answer was actually fine the way it was because Time.parse will always return a string without any SQL. In other words it handles the sanitisation. Your new code is not valid though (e.g. you aren't closing the square brackets on the @from and @to lines). My comment was mostly to warn others that you shouldn't pass user params directly to the database. For example if they decided to use `@from_date = params[:from_date]` then it would be susceptible to an SQL injection attack

Comment: @KNejad Thanks for the suggestion I have updated the syntax error now

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for your use case, I believe checking for `longitude.present? and latitude.present?` is required:

```
my_table.location = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE my_table SET location = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(#{longitude}, #{latitude}, 4326)::geography")) if longitude.present? and latitude.present?
```