# How do I write Rails ActiveRecord update query with dynamic binding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

With `where` we can do `Item.where('stock_amount > ?', 0)`.

**Question**: Is there a way to write in ActiveRecord that will produce the following SQL?

```
UPDATE items SET stock_amount = stock_amount - 10 where id = 1;
```

I have tried

```
Item.update(1, {stock_amount: ['stock_amount - ?', 10]}
```

and it runs but does not produce the SQL I want.

I know I can achieve the same result with more lines like

```
item = Item.find(1)
item.stock_amount = item.stock_amount - 10
item.save
```

and using `exec_update`

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_update('UPDATE items SET stock_amount = stock_amount - $1 WHERE id = $2', 'sql', [[nil, 10],[nil, 1]])
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24520455/188574) is the closest I get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Item.where(id: 1).update_all(["stock_amount = stock_amount - ?", 10])
```

should produce:

```
UPDATE "items" SET stock_amount = stock_amount - 10 WHERE "items"."id" = $1  [["id", 1]]
```

Comment: With Rails 5.1.6, I get little bit different SQL that achieve the same result. `UPDATE "items" SET stock_amount = stock_amount - 10 WHERE "items"."id" IN (SELECT "items"."id" FROM "items" WHERE "items"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "items"."name" ASC)  [["id", 1]]`